# multithreading Graphics

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, animation, draw

I'm trying to implement a program where I draw multiple circles and make them randomly move through the frame. I wanted to create a thread for each circle but for some reason it's not working. 
When I instantiate a couple of circles only one appears in the frame.
Here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Ball extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    private Color color;
    private int xPosition;
    private int yPosition;
    private int xDir;
    private int yDir;
    private int radius;
    private int xSpeed;
    private int ySpeed;
    private static JFrame frame;

    public Ball(int xPos, int yPos) 
    {
        color = new Color((int) (Math.random()*254), (int) (Math.random()*254), (int) (Math.random()*254));
        System.out.println(color);
        radius = 10;
        xPosition = xPos;
        yPosition = yPos;
        xDir = -1;
        yDir = -1;
        xSpeed = 10;
        ySpeed = 10;

    }

    public void paint(Graphics e){
        super.paint(e);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) e;
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(xPosition, yPosition, radius, radius);     
        //setSpeed();
    }

    public void setSpeed()
    {
        xSpeed = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    }

    public void moveBall()
    {
        if(xPosition >= 390)
        {
            xDir *= -1;
        }
        else if(xPosition <= 0)
        {
            xDir *= -1;
        }
        if(yPosition >= 390)
        {
            yDir *= -1;
        }
        else if(yPosition <= 0)
        {
            yDir *= -1;
        }
        xPosition = xPosition + ( xDir * xSpeed);
        yPosition  = yPosition + (yDir * ySpeed);


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        frame = new JFrame("Ball Bouncer");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Ball b1 = new Ball(25, 25);
        Ball b2 = new Ball(50, 50);
        b1.setSpeed();
        //b2.setSpeed();
        Thread a1 = new Thread(b1);
        Thread a2 = new Thread(b2);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println(a2.getState());

        a1.start();

        a2.start();
        System.out.println(a1.getId());
        System.out.println(a2.getId());

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true)
        {
            frame.getContentPane().add(this);

            moveBall();
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You are always adding a `Ball` (which is a `JPanel`) to `BorderLayout.CENTER` at `frame.getContentPane().add(this);`, so only the last one is visible. I wouldn't extend `JPanel` for `Ball` anyway. Also, I would prefer a `Timer` over a new `Thread`.

Comment: *"I wanted to create a thread for each circle"*  Why?  Note that all GUI updates should be on the EDT, of which, there is exactly one.  See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Using a new thread for each ball is very inefficent and won't scale well, it also introduces copious amount of issues with updating the balls on the UI and monitoring other conditions and is generally a bad idea. It would be better to have a class which maintain information about the location of the ball (and maybe some paint method), which are stored in a `List` which a single thread updates and schedules repaints for

Comment: `Ball` really should be a component of any description (especially if you want to be able to update them from outside of the EDT), they should be a generic class which maintains location information (and possibly some paint method and other attributes)

Answer (score 1):

Ball (Your class) extends JPanel.

If you add more than one JPanel to a JFrame, only last one you added will be visible.